# grails/hibernate findOrCreateBy is always creating

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an Address class that I use.

My method call is

```
Address.findOrCreateByAddress1AndAddress2AndCityAndStateAndZipCode(params.address1, params.address2, params.city, params.state, params.zip)
```

While everything I read states this should "find if exists, else create", it creates a new record in the address table.

Here are 2 examples from my address table

```
ID - 1
version - 0 
address1 - 123 Main St
address2 - null
city - P
state - OH
zipCode - 12345

ID - 5
version - 0 
address1 - 123 Main St
address2 - null
city - P
state - OH
zipCode - 12345
```

My Address class

```
class Address {

    String address1
    String address2
    String city
    String state
    Integer zipCode

    static constraints = {
        address2 nullable:true
        shippingAddress nullable:true
        billingAddress nullable:true
    }

    static belongsTo = [shippingAddress: CustomerShippingAddress, billingAddress: CustomerBillingAddress]
}
```

Comment: your assumption is true and a trivial test (even with the `null` there) works as expected.  so the question is, what are the actual data there?  is it `"null"` vs `null` or such things?  can you rule out concurrent access? what DB are you using?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you included your Domain class so we can rule out such things as custom mappings, etc.

Comment: @cfrick added Address class. Using the standard H2 database in devl

Comment: @JoshuaMoore added Domain class

Comment: What version of Grails are you running?